# what's the trader term for return of 3x, 4x, 5x etc

Tags: investing, terminology

There's a trader term for returns that are multiples of the original amount.  I forget what the stem word is.  Suppose it were "ball", tripling your money would be known as a three-ball, quadrupling it as a four-ball, and so on.  What is the stem word?  I've forgotten it, and failed to find it by searching.

Comment: BTW, this sort of terminology can be ambiguous, in that 2x can mean 100% return or 200%.

Answer (score 7):

From [Investopedia - Tenbagger](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/tenbagger.asp#:%7E:text=Key%20Takeaways,times%20its%20initial%20purchase%20price.):

> A tenbagger is an investment that appreciates to 10 times its initial
> purchase price. The term “tenbagger” was coined by legendary fund
> manager Peter Lynch in his book "One Up On Wall Street." While
> tenbagger can describe any investment that appreciates or has the
> potential to increase ten-fold, it is usually used to describe stocks
> with explosive growth prospects. Lynch coined the term because he is
> an avid baseball fan, and “bag” is a colloquial term for base; thus
> “tenbagger” represents two home runs and a double, or the stock
> equivalent of a hugely successful baseball play.

I hear/see 10-bagger frequently, rarely if ever other numbers but it works fine for other numbers. One thing that I dislike about the definition above is that it makes it sound like multiple plays/at bats. I think it's actually a grand slam homerun. With bases loaded a homerun causes the runner on 3rd to touch 1 bag, the runner on 2nd to touch 2 bags, 1st 3 bags, and the batter 4 all bags. 4+3+2+1 = 10. I haven't seen anyone offer that explanation before, but I always thought it made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Two fold
Three fold
Etc..

Example of selling a share for $30 that you purchased for $10:
"I earned three fold of what I put in."

Answer (score 0):

Traders can use any slang or description they like to describe their actions. Some examples could be:

- I got a ten bagger
- I hit a home run
- I tripled my money
- I got a 400% return
- I increased my money five-fold
- I double then redoubled my money

The phrases use could be anything that they want them to be.

Answer (score -1):

#### A scam.

Real investments don't return anywhere close to that much money. If it sounds too good to be true, it probably is, so call an "investment opportunity" that offers a return of tripling or quadrupling your money what it is: a scam.

Comment: It's quite possible to get 10x returns on a high delta position. Day traders who work with derivatives very frequently get that kind of return on individual trades (but not overall).

Comment: "Real investments don't return anywhere close to that much money." – That's not true. Anything that *promises* a tenfold return over less than about (say) 25 years is almost certainly a scam, and yet stocks go up tenfold over much shorter timespans all the time.